# CodeIgniter 3 Unable to locate the model you have specified

Tags: php, codeigniter, heroku

I'm getting this error:

```
Unable to locate the model you have specified: Users_model
```

CodeIgniter is version 3. The filename is `Users_model.php`. It is located at `application\models` and it goes like this:

```
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');
class Users_model extends CI_Model {

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

[...]
}
```

I am calling it from a controller like this:

```
$this->load->model('users_model');
```

Interestingly enough, it works on a local mongoose server, but not when I deploy it to a heroku server.

Comment: try uppercase. `$this->load->model('Users_model');`

Comment: That works locally, both upper and lowercase initials. Actually I tried all sorts of combinations of upper/lower. But none works on heroku, it's like it's really not finding the file.

Comment: did all other models are working fine ? try auto loading this model. and make sure `User_model` file is deployed on heroku.

Comment: Man, finally figured it out after 3 days, Lol. Answering your questions: there were no other models, it was the first one I was trying and yes, Users_model.php was indeed deployed.

But to confirm that it was deployed, I did `heroku run bash` and surfed to the models directory and saw that it was deployed as `users_model.php`, not `Users_model.php`, because the first time I deployed, it was not capitalized and git wasn't updating filename case changes. That's why it worked on the local server, but not on heroku.

To solve that, I did `git config core.ignorecase false`.

Thanks, @Kamran!

Comment: great :) sometime small things create huge problems.

Comment: @sthiago I love you man, you should answer your own question (:

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your git *may* be configured to **ignore case changes** in file names. The effect of this is: any local changes to a filename of a file that has **already been deployed** (i.e. is only being modified) are not mirrored on the remote repository (heroku).

For example, if you first deployed a file with the name `users_model.php` all lowercase. Even if you change the local version of the file to `Users_model.php` with the 'U' capitalized, the remote won't mirror this change.

> **How to solve it**: to tell git to update filename case changes, run the following command:
>
> `git config core.ignorecase false`

Thanks to @Kamram for making me figure this out and @FeanDoe for suggesting that I answer the question.

Comment: Hi friend, can you help me, I'm beginner with codeigniter, where is located git file?

Answer (score 5):

Try this.

1. In your model **file name** should be `users_model.php`.
2. **inside model** it should be (**Users_Model**)

   `class Users_Model extends CI_Model{}`.
3. When you calling  use `$this->load->model('Users_Model');`

Comment: are these rules a change from previous versions of codeigniter? I have not used codeigniter since v2.x and I realize they have made changes with regards to capitalization of letters in file names etc. thanks

Comment: In codeigniter 3, users_model.php should be capitalized like Users_model.php

Answer (score 0):

in folder **"application/models"** you should change your file name from **"users_model.php"** to **"Users_model.php"**